Scale volumetric window content with user resize
I'm trying to scale a volumetric window's content when the user resizes the window. When I use modifier aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill), the content does not resize. Using scaledToFit() doesn't scale, and it inexplicably distorts both the window and the content.
How do I scale the content of a volumetric window when the window is resized?
import RealityKit
import SwiftUI

@main
struct SandboxApp: App {
    var body: some SwiftUI.Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .windowStyle(.volumetric)
        .defaultSize(width: 1, height: 1, depth: 1, in: .meters)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { content in
            content.add(ModelEntity(mesh: MeshResource.generateSphere(radius: 0.25),
                                    materials: [SimpleMaterial(color: .red, isMetallic: false)]))
        }
//        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill) // does not resize
//        .scaledToFill() // does not resize AND distorts volume and content
    }
}


You can do it if you hang on to the Entity and use setScale based on the GeometryProxy3D from GeometryReader3D.
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
struct BasicPhotoView<E>: View where E : Entity & HasModel  {
    var model: E
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader3D { proxy in
            RealityView { content in
                
                content.add(model)
            } update: { content in
                let size = content.convert(proxy.frame(in: .local), from: .local, to: .scene)
                model.resize(box: size)
            }
        }
    }
}

extension Entity : HasModel {
    public func resize(box: BoundingBox, style: Style = .aspectRatio) {
        print(#function)
        
        guard let meshBounds = self.model?.mesh.bounds.extents else {
            print("no model")
            return
        }
        
        // Convert extents to positive size vectors
        let spaceSize = simd_float3(Float(box.extents.x), Float(box.extents.y), Float(box.extents.z))
        let meshSize = simd_float3(meshBounds.x, meshBounds.y, meshBounds.z)
        
        // Calculate scale factors for each dimension
        let scaleFactor = spaceSize / meshSize
        
        switch style {
        case .fill:
            // Use the exact scale factor for each dimension (non-uniform scaling)
            self.setScale(abs(scaleFactor), relativeTo: nil)
            
        case .aspectRatio:
            // Use the minimum scale factor for uniform scaling
            let uniformScale = min(scaleFactor.x, scaleFactor.y, scaleFactor.z)
            let aspectRatioScale = simd_float3(repeating: uniformScale)
            self.setScale(abs(aspectRatioScale), relativeTo: nil)
        }
    }
}


You can easily scale 3D content that resides inside a volumetric window (in RealityView), but without going beyond the 2m X 2m X 2m invisible cuboid. However, you cannot scale a volumetric window at runtime because the volumetric scene size is immutable after creation. Also, if you are using a Model3D view, don't forget to implement model.resizable().

When the resizing handles are dragged, the window resizes. Are you saying that the size of the scene itself is immutable? If so, how would I scale the content when the window size changes. The BOTAnist sample made it look as simple as setting minimum and maximum frame values, but that doesn't seem to work in the example I provided.

I didn't come up with this, it’s written in the official documentation.
